Google App Engine to Python 3 Conversion - from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable
I'm working on converting to python3 with google app engine. I started receiving the error below when calling the url /syncstuff. Can I ask for help diagnosing the error below.
model.py
from .collection import Collection

class Collection(SearchableModel, model.Base):


sync.py
import model


sync.yaml 
service: sync
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sync:app 


@app.route('/syncstuff/', methods=['GET'])
#@ndb.transactional
def collectionsync():
    vnew=model.Collection.query(model.Collection.slug=='new').get()
...

import google.appengine.api

client = ndb.Client()
def ndb_wsgi_middleware(wsgi_app):
    def middleware(environ, start_response):
        with client.context():
            return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    return middleware

app.wsgi_app = ndb_wsgi_middleware(google.appengine.api.wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app))



Seems like you missed adding the Service Account Token Creator role? Also have a look at this Documentation and link.

Thank you. I didn't have to do that for app.yaml/main.py, the default? service when reading/writing to the datastore. Can you help with an example?

Can you elaborate on your issue by sharing the steps you are following and about your infrastructure or the document you are following
to replicate the issue?

app.yaml

url: /.*
script: main.app
secure: always
redirect_http_response_code: 301

sync.yaml
service: sync
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sync:app
The code paths are similar when they query the datastore. The main.py traversals are successful. Is there a reason why the Service Account Token Creator role change would only be relevant to sync?

Don't share code part(app.yml) in comments, Instead update your question to reflect asked information and Also note that Appengine uses the Compute engine in the background. Hence it has to query metadata from the compute engine API. As the error itself indicates that you are unable to get metadata. To achieve that you need Service Account Token Creator role because it lets you create the short-lived credentials like OAuth 2.0 access tokens, which you can use to authenticate with Google APIs and OpenID Connect (OIDC) ID tokens. Hence try adding Token creator role as I have shared above.

@SandeepVokkareni thank you. I created a new question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78408597/google-app-engine-python-2-to-python-3-conversation-main-versus-auxiliary-servi
I may not be in sync with the architecture of app engine.

Do you get this error only when you run your app outside of production (e.g. when you run locally)?

on in Google App Engine. I don't currently have a local environment

Just to be clear - you deployed your application to Google's Servers (production) and then when you access the url via a browser, you get the above error?

yes, this occurrs when deploying to google app engine in google cloud

@ffejrekaburb - I didn't ask if it occurs when deploying. I asked if you've deployed already (deploy is complete) and then you get the error when you try to access the url. The point at which you get the error matters. Can you state exactly when you get the error?

Yes the deployment is complete. The error occurs when deploying.
Subsequent calls yield "Internal Server Error". My initial statement appears to need a revision.

You are saying the deployment is complete and the error occurs when deploying. What does it mean? Can you clarify it?

gcloud deploy exits and returns control to the shell. The error occurs in the log during the deployment.

What is the rpc call used for? The reason I'm asking is to know what are the different components.

What RPC call you are talking about? Is it related to the error you added in question? Edit your question to have clear picture like, what you have tried and share a complete repro by editing your question.

I updated to picture. Yes the RPC stuff mentioned in the error.

As suggested in the above comment, Have you tried enabling the Service Account Token Creator role? If not, can you retry by enabling the role and see whether it is working or not?  Orelse share the steps you are following about your infrastructure to replicate the issue or the document you are following?

@SandeepVokkareni I would like to send you a video, can i send you via direct message?

What do you mean by direct message? If it is possible to share a video as per the Stackoverflow guidelines you can share the link?

I enabled  Service Account Token Creator (2) role for the two accounts I believe are associated. Compute Engine default service account and App Engine default service account and the error occurs when traversing an endpoint in the sync service as triggered by endpoint. Can you help further? I don't know how to traverse on   get_dbs(
this is an ancestor for the error above "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/_datastore_query.py", line 1030, in _datastore_run_query

Ideally it should work after adding the Service Account Token Creator role. It seems like it would require a project inspection to find the issue. It’s better to contact Google support to find the resolution.

Can you help me understand what it is doing? What is the metadata service?

"Required to purchase Standard Support:
An Organization resource
You do not have permission to view the organization associated with the selected project. Please contact your Organization Admin for access.
Support Account Administrator
Please contact your Organization Admin.
You must be assigned Support > Support Account Administrator for the organization in IAM to continue.
"
I tried emailing the audit team that was the initial driver for this and this seems to have bounced.

@NoCommandLine What is the metadata service?
