Google App Engine Python 2 to Python 3 conversation, main versus auxiliary service
I have two services
--- app.yaml ---
service: default
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.95
  max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true

 - url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

--- sync.yaml ---
service: sync
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sync:app 

- url: /.*
  script: sync.app
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

Both query the google datstore with this library.
from google.cloud import ndb
Based upon a response to this card I would need to give access to
"Service Account Token Creator" to sync only?
Google App Engine to Python 3 Conversion - from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable
Why would will this change only be applicable to the sync service? Is a different abstract layer used?
